# Atomizer for aeroponics: growing in vapor and mist, what is this?

Tags: aeroponics

I'm making an Aeroponic system. I just saw this ["Aero-Pot Aeroponics System Review - My new Hydroponics Toy"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAEjobYD-VA), where rather than using a manifold with sprayers he is using an atomizer to make a vapor or fog. It seems "atomizers" are also marketed as "ultrasonic mist" sprayers in this industry.

What are the pros and cons of an aeroponics system built on atomizers rather than sprayers? Does atomizing water result in distribution of suspended nutrients? Do any larger hydroponics systems use this approach?

Answer (score 1):

## Fogponics

Apparently, this is a new thing and it's marketing term is [fogponics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fogponics).

Searching for that term, you'll find a lot of information.

Comment: I have not seen that word before, but terrariums with fogger/atomizer have been available